# Forms not working with web2py in Chrome

Tags: forms, google-chrome, web2py

I'm new to web2py and following the book, I'm trying to follow along with the 3rd Chapter building the images application http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/3#An-image-blog, I'm faced with a problem after building the model and trying to add uploads using the database administration, it doesn't work in chrome, after filling the form and clicking submit, the page refreshes with cleared inputs as new. The form works with other browsers as expected (Firefox, Opera, IE) I'm running on Windows 7.

Anybody knows what is causing such problem ??

Comment: Hard to say. It might be easier to figure this out if you ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py). Please post your complete code there.

Comment: @Anthony, I believe posting it here (via a pastebin) would be better in the long-run as it is really hard to find info on the group.

Comment: That's fine. I was just thinking this might require a bit of back-and-forth to diagnose the problem, and SO isn't really conducive to that kind of process. We can always post the final answer here.

Comment: I'm testing only with chrome my web2py developments, and never got a problem with it...

Comment: Try it in safe mode with extensions disabled.